# converting hex to float 32

Tags: c#, floating-point, hex

I have a hexadecimal `(42 E6 56 00)` which should be translated into this float number: `115.2`, of course it is float `32` (I've got `115.2` using a calculator). Now I want to perform this operation using C#, I use following code but it gives me strange values:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x42E65600);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
    bytes = bytes.Reverse().ToArray();
}
float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

Comment: I've found this code and it seems to be ok:             uint num = uint.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

            byte[] floatVals = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
            float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatVals, 0);

Comment: Put that as an answer..

Answer (score 3):

The better way to write:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 0x42, 0xE6, 0x56, 0x00 }; // Big endian data
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
    Array.Reverse(bytes); // Convert big endian to little endian
}
float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

Note that `BitConverter` uses the platform's endianess.

I tested with an [IEEE-754 Analysis](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/), it seems that your source data is *really* big endian, so this is the correct way to write.

You may not know, but `BitConverter.GetBytes(0x42E65600);` will get `byte[]{ 0x00, 0x56, 0xE6, 0x42 }` on little endian platform.

---

If you insists on writing a hexadecimal literal, you don't need to convert the endianess (because it will always be correct, see @George's comment)

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x42E65600);
float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0); // Always be correct
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I convert between big/little endian? is there any ready-made function?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet You'd probably want to read my edited answer. The endianness things are tricky.

Comment: GetBytes returns a byte array in the platform's endianess. ToSingle takes a byte array in the platform's endianess. So the byte order should never be reversed. (The return of GetBytes is {0x00, 0x56, 0xE6, 0x42} for me.)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a hexadecimal (42 E6 56 00) which should be translated into
>   this float number: 115.2

If that is the case then your data is in big Endian format

```
BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
```

This will determine what your bit converted bitness is so you would want the condition to be

```
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
```

Finally, your endian conversion is wrong. You would not want to reverse the entire array but swap the individual float entries

```
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            Swap<byte>(ref data[i], ref data[data.Length - i - 1]);
        }
```

Combining all these rectification, your code should look something like

```
   static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
    {
        T temp;
        temp = lhs;
        lhs = rhs;
        rhs = temp;
    }
    static byte[] Big2Little(byte[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            Swap<byte>(ref data[i], ref data[data.Length - i - 1]);
        }
        return data;

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x42E65600);
        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            bytes = Big2Little(bytes);
        }
        float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
        System.Console.Out.WriteLine(myFloat);
    }
```

**Note** You can verify your result from the [IEEE Analyzer](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/)

Comment: I don't see any functional differences between your for-loop and reversing the whole array (which has only 4 bytes forming a `float`, anyway).